# How to use padding value with get_keras_embedding

Tags: keras, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I try to integrate gensim's `get_keras_embedding` into a Keras model.

First I do text preprocessing

1. `text_to_word_sequence` converts text into token sequence
2. `w2v.vocab[tok].index` converts words into gensim's word indexes
3. `pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, value=999999)` padding with some value

Then I build a model

```
embedding_layer = w2v.get_keras_embedding(train_embeddings=False)
...
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
...
x = Conv1D(100, kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1)(embedded_sequences)
```

Apparently the problem is with the padding value. The default value is 0 which is 'the' in gensim word2vec, if I use non-existing value it fails with the following error message. What is the right way to use padding with gensim word2vec?

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[48,0] = 999999 is not in [0, 400000)
     [[Node: embedding_1/embedding_lookup = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@embedding_1/embeddings"], validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read, _arg_input_1_0_3)]]
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please include the error message that you mentioned.

Comment: @VegardKT, added

Comment: This is a long shot, but can you try reducing your padding to something small. like 5 and see if you get the same error message?